# AngularJs TypeError: $scope.posts.push is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When i post a detail to an api with angularJs, i got an error like `TypeError: $scope.posts.push is not a function` now how i fix that?
My post code is :

```
 AdminApp.controller('AddVehicleModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$modalInstance','$http','toaster', function ($scope, $rootScope, $modalInstance,$http,toaster) {
$scope.create = function(){
    $http.post(AppCore.getGlobalApiUrl()+'vehicle_type', {"vehicle_type": $scope.post.vehicle_type})
        .success(function(response, status, headers, config){
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            toaster.pop('success', "post", "done");
            $scope.posts.push(response.posts);
            $scope.$apply();
        })
        .error(function(response, status, headers, config){
            $scope.error_message = response.error_message;
        });
};
$scope.cancel = function () {
    $scope.post = "";
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `$scope.posts` as an array anywhere. Above your `$scope.create` definition, just throw in an initializing statement like

```
$scope.posts = [];
```